# Vue.js 2.3 - Element UI Dialog - Sync and Props

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `vue-js 2.3` and `element-ui`. Since the update `2.3` of `vue-js` and the reintroduction of `sync`, things have changed and I have had a hard time figuring out my problem.

Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7o5z7dc1/

#### Problem

The `dialog` is only opened once. When I close it I have this error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "showDialog"

#### Questions

What am I doing wrong?

How can I fix the current situation?

#### EDIT

If I'm creating a `data` I manage to remove the error message but the `dialog` does not close anymore

```
<div id="app">
      <left-panel v-on:show="showDialog = true">></left-panel>
      <popup v-if="showDialog":show-dialog.sync="showDialog"></popup>
    </div>

    <template id="left-panel-template">
      <button @click="$emit('show')">Show Component PopUp</button>
    </template>


    <template id="popup">
        <el-dialog :visible.sync="showDialog" @visiblechange="updateShowDialog">I am the popup</el-dialog>
    </template>


        Vue.component('left-panel', {
      template: '#left-panel-template',
      methods: {
      },
    });

    Vue.component('popup', {
      template: '#popup',
      props : ['showDialog'],
      methods: {
       updateShowDialog(isVisible) {
           if (isVisible) return false;
           this.$emit('update:showDialog', false )
       },
      },
    });

    var vm = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        showDialog: false,
      },
      methods: {

      }
    });
```

Comment: `showDialog` is a prop. You can create a computed property, say `computedShowDialog() { return this.showDialog }` then use this computed

Comment: Would you mind to edit the jsfiddle to illustrate what you propose ? I tried several possibilites with `computed properties` and `data` but I can't make it work completely. If I manage to remove the error message, then the `popup` just does not close

Comment: I don't see the benefit of your popup component, it's only a wrapper around the element UI dialog. My advise would be to just use the Element UI component directly

Comment: @GOB By doing this https://jsfiddle.net/vw8vks6z/ it is indeed working. Bt I'm wondering if you would have a solution even with the wrapper ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot make vue.js element-ui's dialog work while it's inside a child component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49498786/cannot-make-vue-js-element-uis-dialog-work-while-its-inside-a-child-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You avoid the mutation warning by making a copy of the prop and mutating that instead of mutating the property directly.

```
Vue.component('popup', {
  template: '#popup',
  props : ['showDialog'],
  data(){
    return {
        show: this.showDialog
    }
  },
  methods: {
   updateShowDialog(isVisible) {
       if (isVisible) return false;
       this.$emit('update:showDialog', false )
   },
  },
});
```

I also changed your template to handle the `visible-change` event correctly.

```
<el-dialog :visible.sync="show" @visible-change="updateShowDialog">I am the popup</el-dialog>
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7o5z7dc1/2/).

Comment: I know `thank you` comment are not really allowed. But... thank you @Bert

Comment: @bert, your solution worked for me but there was one problem. So, I changed `@visible-change="updateShowDialog"` to `v-on:update:visible="updateShowDialog"` or `@:update:visible="updateShowDialog"` and it worked.