# Cannot make vue.js element-ui's dialog work while it's inside a child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

Here is the parent component:

```
<template lang="pug">
  .wrapper
    el-button(type="primary", @click="dialogAddUser = true") New User
    hr
    // Dialog: Add User
    add-edit-user(:dialog-visible.sync="dialogAddUser")
</template>

<script>
import * as data from '@/components/partials/data'
import AddUser from './partials/AddUser'

export default {
  name: 'users',
  components: { AddUser },

  data () {
    return {
      users: data.users,
      dialogAddUser: false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the child component:

```
<template lang="pug">
  el-dialog(width="75%", title="New User", :visible.sync="dialogVisible", top="5vh")
    div 'el-dialog-body' - content goes here
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'add-user',
    props: {
      dialogVisible: Boolean
    }
  }
</script>
```

I am able to open the `dialog` but when close the dialog using top right button inside the `dialog` then I am getting this error:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten
>   whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or
>   computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated:
>   "dialogVisible"

Later I tried to play and did something like below, but now I cannot even open the `dialog`:

```
<template lang="pug">
  el-dialog(width="75%", title="New User", :visible.sync="visibleSync", top="5vh")
    div 'el-dialog-body' - content goes here 
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'add-user',
    props: {
      dialogVisible: Boolean
    },
    watch: {
      visibleSync (val) {
        this.$emit('update:dialogVisible', val)
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        visibleSync: this.dialogVisible
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `visible.sync` works, the component is emitting an `update:visible` event.

So, to not mutate in the child and, instead, propagate the event to the parent, instead of:

```
:visible.sync="dialogVisible"
```

Do

```
:visible="dialogVisible", v-on:update:visible="visibleSync = $event"
```

Full code:

```
<template lang="pug">
  el-dialog(width="75%", title="New User", :visible="dialogVisible", v-on:update:visible="visibleSync = $event", top="5vh")
    div 'el-dialog-body' - content goes here 
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'add-user',
    props: {
      dialogVisible: Boolean
    },
    watch: {
      visibleSync (val) {
        this.$emit('update:dialogVisible', val)
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        visibleSync: this.dialogVisible
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

As another alternative, you could emit directly from the `v-on` listener and do without the `visibleSync` local property:

```
<template lang="pug">
  el-dialog(width="75%", title="New User", :visible="dialogVisible", v-on:update:visible="$emit('update:dialogVisible', $event)", top="5vh")
    div 'el-dialog-body' - content goes here 
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'add-user',
    props: {
      dialogVisible: Boolean
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'll try to reproduce, gimme a sec

Comment: But here https://stackoverflow.com/a/44287716/1292050 there is one issue, I changed `@visible-change="updateShowDialog"` and used your code and it worked `v-on:update:visible="updateShowDialog"` or `@:update:visible="updateShowDialog"`

Comment: Found it. Please check updated answer. It should be: `:visible="dialogVisible", v-on:update:visible="visibleSync = $event"`

Comment: I have also added another alternative, shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I think a nice way to handle this is to:

1. Use a prop to pass the visible state from the parent to the child.
2. Forward `el-dialog`'s [`close`](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dialog#events) event from the child to the parent.
3. In the parent, handle the `close` event to set the prop to `false`.

Child:

```html
<el-dialog :visible="visible" @close="$emit('close')">
```

```js
export default {
  props: {
    visible: Boolean
  },
  ...
```

Parent (assuming you store the open state in `state.modalOpen`):

```html
<el-button @click="state.modalOpen = true">Open Modal</el-button>
<child-component :visible="state.modalOpen" @close="state.modalOpen = false" />
```